# Task object Comments Field not showing up in Data Loader

Tags: data-loader, tasks

I am trying to load data into the Task object. The Comments field appears to be a standard field on the Task object and I have permission to view and edit this field. Comments does not show up as a field available for mapping in the Data Loader. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `Description` field. The `Comments` field is just a label on the `Description` field. You can see this in the setup menu, under App Setup, Customize, Activities, Task Fields.

Screenshot from the App Setup menu:

[image: Standard Field Menu]